# Can someone provide a list of the things to ideally do when rooting?

Tags: rooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I root my phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone)

I have found some decent guides on how to root your Android device on various forums, but I would interested in hearing what everyone hear feels is the ideal checklist when rooting.  For instance, when I did my first root recently it was something like this:

1. Download and run z4root.
2. Download, install, and run Boostrap Recovery
3. Create a backup of the current ROM
4. Download, install, and run Titanium backup
5. Install apps that need root to run
   ... etc

If there is more to add, please let me know.

NOTE: Additionally, if this question is too device-centric, let me know and I will either edit it or close it.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think you should edit the question for a specific device as methods vary significantly between devices.

Comment: Actually, scratch that, this one is totally covered here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-phone/1185#1185

Comment: While the question FoleyIsGood points out does not completely cover "good practices", it is intended to be a canonical question with a complete answer.  As such, feel free to add your knowledge to that answer and we will do the same; dividing it up seems like a bad idea.